# How to design and add images in the categories section?

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

I want to know how can I design the categories section like the image provided in this [link](http://postimg.org/image/7jw08v1qh/).

These are my questions:

1) How to add the "New" and "Hot" image above and next to the categories?

2) How to make "Tops", "Bags" have sub-categories?

3) And I have the image of the bullet-arrow-pointer, how can I add it in front of the category and make it move when I hover my mouse to the name. (like Tunics)

4) Last, how do I make the categories have two rows? Because right now, mines just going straight down.

Comment: You can use bootstrap to layout your page as show in the image. 1) [bootstrap-label](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels) 2) [bootstrap-dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-dropdowns)

Comment: you used ultimo theme. this theme is great. you can find all option from magento admin. when you add or edit category the option is availabe to set the "New" or "Hot" and also change the color into configuration tab

Comment: What if I want to make the bullet-arrow point right when I hover my mouse to the name? do I use Css or javascript? I already have the image.

Comment: @renishkhunt what about the bullet-point? do you use this theme also? do you mind adding me as friend on skype or other apps? Please..

Comment: @Vinsin send me your skype id. I send a request to you at tonight in  indian timezone and yes also i used this theme. Thanks

Comment: @renishkhunt do you know how to fix the "Please wait..." bug when ever I add new category, the "Please Wait..." never goes away.

Comment: @Vinsin this is not an error. your internet connection is slow or once clear magento cache.

Comment: @renishkhunt This is my skype ID: xkamivm Please add me on skype.

Comment: @Vinsin ok i send a request tonight.

Comment: hey, please accept my skype request thanks